# Change of email address in peer-review system

Tags: email, affiliation, peer-review

My goal is to serve as journal reviewers as much as possible, and I have recently changed affiliation. I have published several papers using my old affiliation's email address which is now closed since leaving, but I have set up an automatic reply message informing senders of my new email in the Office365 system which is good for 1 year after account closing. I wonder what will happen if an editor finds me as a potential reviewer based on my publications and reach out to me using my old institute's email address. Do most submission systems (eg. Manuscript Central) handle automatic replies well? Do journals or editors typically take effort to research on reviewers' recent contact info before reaching out? Also I do have an ORCID account and a personal webpage, but as my name is very common I don't think it helps much in this situation.

Comment: The various journals I have reviewed for allow you to change your contact address and email online.

Comment: General advice: Use a non-university email for those things.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much time the editor is spending on the journal. When an invitation email bounces, the editor will receive an email. It's good practice then to cancel the invitation, because otherwise one could easily mislead oneself that the reviewer might still accept. If the bounce email includes a redirect, then it's a simple matter of changing the reviewer's email and inviting again. But doing this for reviewer after reviewer (an editor can conceivably have a couple of papers a day to handle, each of which needs 5+ invitations) gets tedious quickly. The editor might get tired, in which case a sufficiently motivated publisher can still pick up the ball ... but no guarantees. In your case the redirect will only work for a year, which might not suffice since the editor might be inviting based on your papers published over a year ago.

The easiest way to update your email is to log on to the system yourself and update your information. If you can't do this, emailing the publisher (the journal's full-time staff) is the next-best way.

Comment: Editors need to look up referee emails all the time. And finding good referees is hard enough. If they were to remove anyone whose email changed from their database, they would soon run out of referees.

Answer (score 1):

In Manuscript Central, the return address is configurable by the journal. We then send the email "on behalf of" that address, using SPF records when appropriate. Assuming the journal monitors the email address it used to send the invitation, they should see the automatic reply. However, you should always keep your details up to date if you want to participate in the journals peer review activities.

I am an employee of ScholarOne, but this post represents my personal opinion only!